# Could not connect to SMTP host) error while sending mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am facing (Could not connect to SMTP host) error while sending mail by using javax.mail.jar. I am able to send mail through smtp.gmail.com, but when i am trying to connect to my company mail server i am getting the error. I tried from telnet and i am able to send mail from telnet and another python program is also running which is sending mail using the same mail server(ip and port), our bugzilla server is also running on same ip and port and it is successfully sends the mail. I tried to configure the same from java as well as from log4j through SMTP appender but no sucess.

Please guid me.

Thanks In Advance

my code as below -

```
    private Session getSession()
{
  Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator
   .getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
  //properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtpServer);
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

  return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
}

private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
{
  private final javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication authentication;
  public Authenticator()
  {
    authentication =
        new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
  }
@Override
protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
  return authentication;
}
}

public boolean sendEmail() throws MessagingException
{
    boolean isSuccess = false;
    String setBody = "";
    String setSubject = "";
    try
    {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());
        setReceipients(message);
        message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[]
        { new InternetAddress(emailFrom, "Notification") });
        setSubject = emailSubject;
        message.setSubject(setSubject);
        setBody = emailBody + "\nThis is a System Generated Mail";
        message.setContent(setBody, "text/plain");
        Transport.send(message);
        log.info("Mail Sent Successfully to - " + emailTo);
        isSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
    {
        log.error("Error in sending Mail without Attachment- "
            + ex.getMessage());
        log.warn("Mail Sending Failed for Mail ID:" + emailTo);
    }
    catch (SendFailedException e)
    {
        log.error("Invalid Addresses \"" + emailTo + "\" specified:"
            + e.getMessage());
        log.warn("Mail Sending Failed for Mail ID:" + emailTo);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Error in sending Mail without Attachment- "
        + e.getMessage());
            log.warn("Mail Sending Failed for Mail ID:" + emailTo);
    }
    return isSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code. My crystal ball is a little clouded today.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaMail FAQ has [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

It would help to see the debug output from JavaMail.

Possibly you have a firewall or anti-virus program that is blocking port 25.